# Play Framework 2.1: Scala: how to get the whole base url (including protocol)?

Tags: scala, request, playframework-2.1

Currently I am able to get the host from the [request](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Request), which includes domain and optional port. Unfortunately, it does not include the protocol (http vs https), so I cannot create absolute urls to the site itself.

```
object Application extends Controller {
  def index = Action { request =>
    Ok(request.host + "/some/path") // Returns "localhost:9000/some/path"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get the protocol from the request object?

Comment: Why do you need absolute links? (what is your use case?)

Comment: A couple of examples where I need absolute urls: 1) a json api that returns paths to other urls on the site (from assets to other api entry points, etc). 2) Sending emails out to users. 3) sharing urls on external sites (posting to apis, etc)

Comment: More use cases: generating `sitemap.xml` and `rss.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your portnumber will give you if it's http or https.

Start your Play server with https support `JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttps.port=9001 play start`

Here's a code snippet (you can make the validation more stable with a regex, take the https port number from properties ...)

```
def path = Action { request =>
    val path = 
      if(request.host.contains(":9000"))
        "http://" + request.host + "/some/path"
      else
        "https://" + request.host + "/some/path"
    Ok(path)
  }
```

The code will return

```
http://ServerIp:9000/some/path if it's thru http
https://ServerIp:9001/some/path if it's thru https
```

Comment: For me https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaRouting#Reverse-routing works fine!

Comment: How is this an accepted answer? The port number is *not* a reliable method of fetching the protocol, especially if the request is passing through proxies.

Answer (score 12):

Actually there's a simple way to do it using Call class that reverse routers use to achieve similar thing.
Given that you are within the scope of implicit request, you can do something like this:

```
new Call(request.method, input.request).absoluteURL()
```

and it will provide you with the complete url (protocol, host, route and parameters).

Comment: Interesting, but didn't quite work for me; it returned http instead of https; the rest was correct.

Comment: @AndrewSwan do note that absoluteURL has an optional boolean parameter to specifiy if you want the url secured or not. If you write `new Call(request.method, input.request).absoluteURL(true)` that line of code will work for you under a secure environment. Unfortunately there is no way to get the "protocol" from the request (thus knowing if is secured or not) but there is some workaround explained here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2427

Answer (score 7):

In Play 2.3 and later you can use [the `secure` property of the Request](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Request) class.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is.

- Play Framework 2.0 itself does not support https, see: [play-framework [2.0] HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924848/play-framework-2-0-https)
- The implementation of [`absoluteURL` method of the `Call`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Call.java#L45) class of the Play Framework 2.0 does not suggest it.

A workaround is to use a [protocol relative urls](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) using `//domain.com/path`.

This however does not help you with links in email. In that case you could put the protocol in the `application.conf`. In most cases the difference is made because production supports https and development does not.

I have yet to find a situation where the above workarounds do not work.

Comment: However play 2.1 does support https even if it's not proper documented and the recommended way is to have a fronting https server.

Comment: Yes, adding a configuration parameter would work, but since this is something easy to get in other languages, I assumed it would be as easy with Play!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to pass the beginning of the url as an additional parameter from javascript.
The application.conf solution does not work for me, because the same application is accessible on http and https but from different subnet and domain.