# How to read scheme(http/https) from request object

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am new to Scala & Play would like to know if there is a way I can check URL scheme (http/https) using [request provided by Play api](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/api/scala/play/api/mvc/Request.html) ?  I tried some properties mentioned in the document they did not work the way i expected not it provided scheme in URI as well.

Is there way I can get scheme in template using Play request api ? Any inputs would be helpful.

```
//code
  h2.host
    = request.path
    = request.method
    = request.uri
    = request.domain
    = request.host
// output
  <h2 class="host">
    /test/8549
    GET
    /test/8549
    localhost
    localhost:9000
  </h2>
```

Comment: @applicius I have some links in page which gets generated dynamically...  relative links solves problem but for printing link on paper needed absolute URL. Hence needed way to for url by reading schema://domain:port/ part from the request. hope that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find these data in Request unfortunately, you have two options:

- Determine protocol basing on application port like [showed in answer for other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14875497/1066240)
- Use some [front-end HTTP server](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/HTTPServer) and add `X-Forwarded-Proto` header, so you can check its value in your action.

For an example if you'll use Apache you need to add these lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"
    …
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    …
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Play 2.6 at least (I haven't checked other versions, I admit), the accepted answer is no longer sufficient. You can determine whether http or https was used as follows:

```
request.connection.secure
```

If this value is true, https was used, otherwise http.